# Use of sample_weight in gradient boosting classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I have the following code for gradient boosting classifier to be used for binary classification problem.

```
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    #Creating training and test dataset
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =        
    train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.30,random_state=1)

    #Count of goods in the training set
    #This count is 50000
    y0 = len(y_train[y_train['bad_flag'] == 0])

    #Count of bads in the training set
    #This count is 100
    y1 = len(y_train[y_train['bad_flag'] == 1])

    #Creating the sample_weights array. Include all bad customers and 
    #twice the number of goods as bads

    w0=(y1/y0)*2
    w1=1

    sample_weights = np.zeros(len(y_train))
    sample_weights[y_train['bad_flag'] == 0] = w0
    sample_weights[y_train['bad_flag'] == 1] = w1

    model=GradientBoostingClassifier(
    n_estimators=100,max_features=0.5,random_state=1)
    model=model.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel(),sample_weights)
```

My thinking about writing this code is as follows:-

1. sample_weights will allow model.fit to select all 100 bads and 200 goods from the training set and this same set of 300 customers will be used to fit 100 estimators in forward stage-wise fashion. I want to undersample my training set because the two response classes are highly imbalanced. Please let me know if my understanding of the code is correct?
2. Also, I would like to confirm that n_estimators=100 means that 100 estimators will be fit on the same set of 300 customers. This also means that there is no bootstrapping in gradient boosting classifier as seen in bagging classifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As far as I understand, this is not how it works. By default, you have `GradientBoostingClassifier(subsample = 1.0)` which means that the sample size that will be used at each stage (for each of the `n_estimators`) will be the same as in your original dataset. The weights will not change anything to the size of the subsample. If you want to enforce 300 observations for each stage, you need to set `subsample = 300/(50000+100)` in addition to the weight definition.
2. The answer is no. For each stage, a new fraction `subsample` of observations will be drawn. You can read more about it here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#gradient-boosting. It says:

   > At each iteration the base classifier is trained on a fraction subsample of the available training data.

   So, as a result, there is some bootstraping combined with the boosting algorithm.

Comment: Thanks Maxime. Another quick question, how would this work in Adaboost Classifier? This classifer does not have subsample parameter but support sample_weight in the fit.

Comment: Glad it answered your question!
AdaBoost is another classification algorithm, and it does not involve any sampling for each estimator. In short, AdaBoost assigns weights to each observation and updates them at each step to assign more weight to misclassified points. Using sample_weight for AdaBoost will just change the initialization of these weights

Comment: Thanks Maxime. If I understand correctly now, sample_weight works differently with different ensembling classifiers. In bagging classifier and random forest, this can be used to control the number of observations for each classs in each estimator. In adaboost and gradient boosting classifiers, this can be used to assign weights to the misclassified points. Gradient boosting classifier also has a subsample parameter which can be used in conjunction with sample weight to control the number of observations used to each estimator.